# Python: API Get requests returns as 1 index in a list

Tags: python, api

I am trying to:

request Get to https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search (public api without auth)

But the random response is returned in a list, not a dict, so I'm having troubles getting the url value I need.

Script:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search?format=json")

print(r.json())
```

Response:

```
[{'id': 'QBvGwfKLW', 'url': 'https://cdn2.thedogapi.com/images/QBvGwfKLW.jpg', 'width': 2322, 'height': 4128}]
```

Script when trying to get the 'url' value out of it:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search?format=json")

# parse response and ask the value of key "url"
link = r.json()["url"]
print(link)
```

Error:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Try: `link = r.json()[0]["url"]`

Comment: Well take the list out of the dictionary first.

Answer (score 0):

Solution posted by @user56700

Try: link = r.json()[0]["url"]